# JavaFX Scenebuilder moving elements inside StackPane

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to move things such as buttons and labels that I put inside a StackPane since I want these things to stay centered when minimizing or maximizing windows. When I put everything I want into the StackPane, they all get centered and layered up on each other. How am I able to move these elements around in the StackPane if it's possible or how will I be able to keep everything centered when resizing the window?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use StackPane? I would suggest using AnchorPane for simple placing of elements.

Comment: @vicky96 How would i be able to keep it centered when resizing the window though? I originally used AnchorPane.

Comment: are you using a scenebuilder?

Answer (score 2):

You edit their TranslateX and TranslateY properties. for instance

```
Label label1 = new Label();
label1.setText("0");
label1.TranslateX(-10.0); //<< moves the label 10 pixels to the left.
```

if you are using Scene Builder you can edit these properties on the right under the "layout" tab.